# How to get a list of simple products from a configureable product

Tags: php, magento

i have the following code

```
$id = 19654;
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$prod->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=> array($id)));
$prod->load();
```

using the following code

```
foreach($prod as $_prod)
{
     var_dump($_prod->getData());
}
```

i can view almost all the data accosted with the configurable product i'm looking at, what i'm missing is at minimum, a list of entity_id's for the simple products that are associated with it

in terms of the database, i know the link between simple and configurable product is in either catalog_product_relation, catalog_product_super_link and/or catalog_product_link, ofcause, since i'm using a collection i can't just use an INNER JOIN

i'm running this code off from a test.php page in the root directory of my magento install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);


if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
    $AssociatedProduct = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts(); 
}
```

Or

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($col as $simple_product){
       var_dump($simple_product->getId());
    }
}
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/41874/